# How can I use location aware geolocation to find local businesses on a web app?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, geolocation

I am trying to set up a mobile web app that uses the geolocation feature to find local restaurants, bars, stores, etc. based on your current location.  I have looked at a lot of tutorials and tried a lot of different things but I am not really seeing anything that explains what I am looking for.  Basically, step 1 it will ask to use your location and you confirm, step 2 it shows your location on a map and then step 3 it shows local businesses with markers. Is there a way to add this feature without having to add a table to call to (which was the only way I have seen it somewhat accomplished but not really)?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) which will provide you with practically any kind of information about what's nearby.

Parse the data and provide it to your [mapview](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) as [annotations](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html).